# iFrame on Javascript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am having problems with `iframe` tag. I want to load other `html` file inside a `div` container through an `iframe`.

Here is my sample code from `javascript` file:

```
$('#MenuOpen').live('click', function (e) {
        if ($("#openIframe").length == 0)
            $("#openFileIframeContainer").html('<iframe id="openIframe" src="example.html"></iframe>');

        $(this).parent("ul").hide();
        showFullscreenDialog($("#MenuOpenText"));
    });
```

And here the `example.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <title>example</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form2" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <label for="file">things...</label>
        <input name="file" id="file" type="file"><br>

        <label for="rate">more things</label>
        <select id="rate" name="rate">
            <option selected="selected">25.0</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for="Codepage">Code page:</label>
        <select id="codePage" name="codePage">
                    <option selected="selected">iso-8859-1</option>
       </select><br>
       <input value="Load" type="submit">
    </form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { parent.openfile(); });
</script>
</body>
```

The problem is I can not load the file `example.html` (on 'src' iframe tag). Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look console for any exception ?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Does the console show any errors? Have you confirmed that the iframe is being added to the DOM? Do you see the attempt to load example.html in the Net tab? Does the request get made? Does it get a response?

Comment: Seems I am having problems with POST:
Incoming text: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /Folder was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port

Comment: That's odd, since you don't mention the URL `/Folder` anywhere in the code you've shared with us.

Comment: Sorry!
`function openfile()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Folder",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("hello")
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus);
                alert("Incoming text: " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Then a 404 is just a 404. Your URL is wrong.

Comment: I understand the 404, but the URL is correct, I checked it lot of times and I can't figure out what is it